# GeckoFX showing error when disposing

Tags: c#, browser, dispose, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX 13 for my desktop application. So I have a main form which is opening another form with GeckoWebBrowser when required. I am using another Gecko browser into my main form also. Everything is working fine except when I am closing the application its showing this error

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be
>   used.

Its a dispose related problem. I know as 2nd form is a different thread thats why showing this error. But I need to know the solution. I did not have this problem with GeckoFX-8. Any solution or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace? Are you accessing GeckoFx components from the non GUI thread?

Comment: @Tom: I dont have an error stack. You see I cant even handle it using try catch.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
   GeckoWebBrowser.Dispose();
   Xpcom.Shutdown();
   base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: Well.. I tried this solution before. Its not working with geckoFx-13. Its definitely a bug. I already reported it to them. But by the meantime I am using geckoFx-14. And its working flawlessly. Thank you though.